# Informational resource requests

Tags: discussion

What is the difference between [resource-request](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) and [resource-information](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-information)? In theory, any answer to a [resource-request](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) question would include information about that resource, so why do we have two tags? If you know, please tell me, if not, I recommend we supercollide these tags and merge [resource-information](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-information) into [resource-request](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) because it's older.

Comment: Annoyingly I don't have the reputation to fix the typo in the title. Can someone fix it please? :-)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to give resource-information some text implying that such questions ask for information about a specific resource (or  a class of resources). So, the asker names a resource.

On the other hand, resource-request is for when the OP doesn't have a resource in mind and wants help in finding one given a description of the need.

So in some sense they can be inverses of each other

- find me info about resource *mumble*
- I need a resource that matches the following info.

Or, we could just drop one of them, but the questions with resource-information become a bit problematic.

Comment: I agree that they are basically inverses, and that we need both.

Comment: I see the distinction, but why does it matter in terms of searching for questions? I think that this distinction will be forgotten and ignored if we make it.